# Find the volume of the paraboloid $z = 3 - x^2 - y^2$

Tags: integration, analysis, multivariable-calculus, volume

Find the volume below the graph of the paraboloid $z=3-x^2-y^2$. I have to calculate this integral without using polar coordinates.

The integration's limits are not specified so I've assumed that the volume is between the $xy$ plane and the graph. If so, I end up having $0 \leq z \leq 3-x^2-y^2$ as a domain of integration but I don't know how to use it in order to write and calculate the integral.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bounds on $x$ and $y$ are $-\sqrt3$ to $\sqrt3$, as the intersection of the paraboloid with the $xy$-plane is the circle $x^2+y^2=3$. This gives us the integral
$$\int_{-\sqrt3}^{\sqrt3}\int_{-\sqrt{3-x^2}}^{\sqrt{3-x^2}}\int_0^{3-x^2-y^2}1\,dz\,dy\,dx$$
which I leave to you to evaluate.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I've another doubt, in any case the strategy to adopt is putting each variables equal to zero to find the limts for each integral?

Comment: @Schiele You find the boundaries, which give you the bounds of integration, and then since this is volume the integrand is one.

Comment: Even if it was the surface I would have had the integrand equal to one?

Comment: @Schiele The integrand is only one if you are finding the volume. For surface area, you would need a parametrisation of the surface.

Comment: Oh right, thank you